# okta oidc - Where/How do I find my jwks_uri?

Tags: openid-connect, okta, okta-api

I've already posted this question in okta community but haven't received an answer yet.
Hello!

Can someone explain how to find the **jwk_uri**? I was looking at the docs here:

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/*keys

It says:

> Note: Looking for how to obtain the jwks_uri for your org or custom
> authorization server? See the well-known OpenID metadata endpoint and
> the well-known OAuth 2.0 metadata endpoint.

but when I click on the links provided I see this:

> Custom Authorization Server--GET
>
> https://${yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/${authorizationServerId}/.well-known/openid-configuration

so now... where do I find my authorizationServerId and is the above now the jwks_uri url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the URL of this form for your system:

- https://dev-xxx.oktapreview.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Then find the `jwks_uri` value in the JSON response, which will be similar to this:

- https://dev-xxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys

Answer (score 1):

On left menu
Security->API->Click on your Authorization Server-> Settings
here you can find the Metadata URI which contains your Auth Server ID.

Your jwks_uri should be:

https://dev-xyz.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/keys?client_id=yourClientID
where yourClientID is the clientID of your application, you can find it under the left menu Applications->Application-> under your application name.